# Database transaction not rolling back with laravel for tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to use the `use DatabaseTransactionTrait` for my test case on laravel in order to reset each transaction after each test.

My test cases are using a specific environnement file (.env.testing)

So I finished to create my own TestCase class :

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    ...
}
```

With my own `CreateApplication` trait :

```
trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        Hash::setRounds(4);

        return $app;
    }
}
```

And each test will extend this new TestCase class and perform database transaction using factories :

```
class UserPhoneFeatureTest extends TestCase
{
    ...
}
```

But, transactions are not roll back after tests.

I went into the laravel's `DatabaseTransactions` code and when i dump the connection name, it says : null

```
trait DatabaseTransactions
{
    /**
     * Handle database transactions on the specified connections.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beginDatabaseTransaction()
    {
        $database = $this->app->make('db');


        foreach ($this->connectionsToTransact() as $name) {
            dd($name), // null
        }
    }
}
```

There is something i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: First, remove the `loadEnvironmentFrom` as it will automatically load `.env.testing`, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#environment-configuration)... Then, do you have a "different" connection name than the default?

Comment: yes, i have two different connection in my project. Each test can transac to any connection

Comment: okay, if you check the [`Trait`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf9f8f702f8f8847d95e7a6c79771ccf93370344/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseTransactions.php#L38-L47), you will see you have to define the connections to transact as an array in a property called `connectionsToTransact`, and you have to put the name of the connections as values.